# One instance for one callback Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have this code

```js
function test(param){
    console.log(param);
}

$('div').each(function(){
     div_id = $(this).attr('id')
     $(this).on('mousemove', function(){
          test(div_id)
     });
});
```

But in my `console.log`, I have always the last value (the id of my last div).

How is it possible to have "one instance" of my callback function at each time?

Thank you!

Comment: `div_id = $(this).attr('id')` to `const div_id = $(this).attr('id')`

Comment: You need a closure to maintain scope of `div_id` within the `mousemove` event handler. ***However the entire problem is moot***, as you should avoid the `each()` and just retrieve `this.id` for the target div within the `mousemove` event

Comment: `div_id` is a global variable and its being overridden in the loop, you should change it to `const` or `let`.

Comment: This is why we define our variables. This is why we define our variables. This is why we define our variables. This is why we define our variables. This is why we define our variables. Use a tool like eslint in your IDE so it yells at you when you forget to define variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the eventhandler for multiple elements at once. Like so:

```js
function test(param){
    console.log(param);
}

$('div').on('mousemove', function(){
    test($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need make local variable to save data not globaly. So you can reinit data of div ID

```
`
function test(param){
    console.log(param);
}

$('div').each(function(){
 add here --> **var** div_id = $(this).attr('id')
     $(this).on('mousemove', function(){
          test(div_id)
     });
});`
```